# How to generate x axis values from a dataframe column in matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Using jupyter notebook, I am reading in census data about baby names from a Google Sheet, and importing matplotlib.pyplot

```
import pandas as pd
Baby_Names_DF = pd.read_clipboard()
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I then execute the pandas dataframe

```
Baby_Names_DF
```

[image]

then I execute this

```
Baby_Names_DF.plot()
plt.show()
```

which renders this

[image]

How can I delete the integer index column of the dataframe, or just call for the "year" column to be the x axis?

Comment: set `year` as index: `df.set_index('Year').plot()`

Comment: thank you very much @MaartenFabré. How do I list this as the answer to my question and give you credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instruct `matplotlib` what should be the `x-axis`. Easiest way is to set `Year` as `index`:

```
df.set_index('Year').plot()
```